# Convert webp into same directory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the program in a loop of creating webp images, yet an error is ocurring.
This has to save images in the same directory of the original files in a folder named "webp".

```
param (
    [switch]$downloadLibWebp,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateRange(1, 100)]
    [int]$compressionFactor = 80,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateRange(1, 6)]
    [int]$compmethod = 6,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Directory
)

        mkdir "$Directory\webp"
        cd "$Directory\webp"
        Get-ChildItem $Directory | ForEach-Object {
            cwebp.exe -q $compressionFactor -mt -m $compmethod $_.fullname -o "$($_.basename).webp"
        }
        cd $PSScriptRoot
```

Comment: By the way it is working, but there are errors...

Comment: We'll need to see those error messages then so we can determine that they are PowerShell related errors and not– as I suspect– cwebp.exe related errors.

Comment: Add switch `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` command, so you do not also iterate DirectoryInfo objects. Now it is also trying to perform the action on the newly created `webp` folder itself..